# Asp.net repeater based Modal with ContentTemplate needs eval passed to parameter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I believe a few friends and I have coded each other into a bit of a corner. Here's what's happening: We have an aspx page building a table of Entries using a repeater, and each row has its respective EntryID. Each row has a link to a modal that displays more detailed information, which we create on the fly with a div template and an eval('EntryID') on the repeater.

The problem now is we have a ContentTemplate we use with an UpdatePanel for a series of LinkButton presses the user can follow to alter the Entry. The issue is that we pass all of the information for the Modal details via a Javascript call that opens the modal, and I need to somehow get this information to the code behind for the LinkButton's onclick call.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="StatusUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlStatus" runat="server">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnlStatusMain" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatusText" runat="server" Text="Our validator returned a yellow status for this entry"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnChangeStatusToGreen" runat="server" OnClick="ChangeStatusToGreen_Click">Change status to green</asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlStatusConfirm" runat="server" CssClass="hideDiv">
                                        Are you sure?<br />
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnCancelChangeStatus" runat="server" OnClick="CancelChangeStatus_Click" CssClass="grayText">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                                        &nbsp;|&nbsp;

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnProceedChangeStatus" runat="server" OnClick="ProceedChangeStatus_Click" CommandArgument="">Yes, proceed</asp:LinkButton>

                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The link in question being lnkbtnProceedChangeStatus.

The rest of the modal is template divs and tables that we use the Javascript call to populate with the appropriate information using html inserts. I'm thinking some sort of post back, but am not sure what would be the best way to go about it. Any ideas?